# How to remove datatype from value in config file with typesafe?

Tags: scala, typesafe, typesafe-config

I have a config file `beam-template.conf` which has different properties like

```
   `beam.agentsim.agents.rideHail.keepMaxTopNScores = "int | 1"
    beam.agentsim.agents.rideHail.minScoreThresholdForRepositioning = "double | 0.1"`
```

I am trying to get the properties values like this.

```
  Configfactory.parseFile(new File(path/beam-template.conf)).entrySet().asScala.foreach { entry =>
    if (!(userConf.hasPathOrNull(entry.getKey))) {
      logString+="\nKey= " + entry.getKey + " ,Value= " + entry.getValue.render
    }
}
```

So the problem is this that the values also include their datatypes like

```
value = int | 1
value = double | 0.1
```

I need only the actual values like `value = 1` and `value = 0.1` instead of including their datatype. So please suggest some solution so that I can remove the datatype from their values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the type of 'int | 1' is String.

Then you can use:

```
def toValue[A](value: String): A = {
  val valStr = value.split("\\|").last.trim()
  (value.split("\\|").head.trim() match {
    case "double" => valStr.toDouble
    case "int" => valStr.toInt
    case other => valStr
  }).asInstanceOf[A]
}
println(toValue[Int]("int | 1"))
println(toValue[Double]("double | 1.1"))
println(toValue[String]("hello"))
```

I updated this to a general function. I also saw that `|` must be escaped.