# How to a get substring after splited a string in scala?

Tags: string, scala, split

I have some Strings like

```
    val value1 = """int | 10"""
    val value2 = """double | 0.1"""
    val value3 = """duration | 60s"""
```

This means that `"int | 10"` itself a String.
I want to get the values like `10 , 0.1 , 60s` from these Strings. I am new to scala so please let me know how can I achieve this value.

.

Comment: @pme showed you how to do it in the answer to [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53425771/how-to-remove-datatype-from-value-in-config-file-with-typesafe) from an hour ago.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove datatype from value in config file with typesafe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53425771/how-to-remove-datatype-from-value-in-config-file-with-typesafe)

Answer (score 0):

Their are multiple ways to do this. I'm sharing one such approach.

```
val value1 = """int | 10"""
val value2 = """double | 0.1"""
val value3 = """duration | 60s"""

println(value1.split("\\|")(1).trim)
println(value2.split("\\|")(1).trim)
println(value3.split("\\|")(1).trim)
```

**Result**

10

0.1

60s

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression match is perhaps the most flexible, though not the most efficient:

```
def extract(valueString: String): Option[String]  = {
  val ValueMatch = """.*\|\s*([^\s]+)\s*""".r

  valueString match {
    case ValueMatch(v) => Some(v)
    case _ => None
  }
}
```

You could also update the regular expression to extract the type as well as the value, and then check that the value conforms to the correct type, and return a value of the correct type.